# vorbis and vorbisenc libraries not found

Tags: c, macos, wav, vorbis

I need to retrieve vorbis and vorbisenc libraries to compile a C program. I tried to download vorbis lib sources in http://xiph.org/downloads/ but each time, there are problems for compiling this lib. Do you know where I can download these lib (.h and .so ) ?

I work on MacOSX.
Thanks

EDIT :
Finally, I succeed to install the library by downloading an older version. But now, I encounter another problem in compiling my program with this library :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libFLAC.dylib, missing required architecture        x86_64 in file /usr/local/lib/libFLAC.dylib (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_sf_close", referenced from:
  _main in ccucQ4qH.o
"_sf_open", referenced from:
  _main in ccucQ4qH.o
"_sf_readf_double", referenced from:
_read_n_samples in ccucQ4qH.o
"_sf_strerror", referenced from:
_main in ccucQ4qH.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```